# Laravel 5.5 remove email field from password reset form

Tags: email, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, change-password, forgot-password

I need to remove email field from password reset form at which user come by clicking link send via email. I don't want users to re-type their email again during resting password as they have already verified their email. This question has been asked several times but most of the questions are not answered yet and others are not working. I have gone through this discussion but they suggest of editing core file which is very risky. So anyone found it's solution yet?

Comment: If you know how to generate reset token then you can send user a custom url from which you can pass two variables such as token and emailid or token and userid. eg- http://website.com/password/customreset / {email}/{token}

Comment: I think this was done as a security feature - the token is hashed similar to a password and needs an identifier (the email) in order for the app to know what hash to compare it to in the database. If clicking the link they get in the email is enough verification for you, then hashing the token shouldn't be necessary and you might just override the functions that set and check the token so they produce a random unhashed token. Never edit core files - extend and override them if you absolutely need to

Answer (score 3):

This is the way you create a reset token manually

```
$email="example@gmail.com";
$token=hash_hmac('sha256', Str::random(40), env("APP_KEY"));
DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', '=', $email)->delete();
DB::table('password_resets')->insert(
        ['email' => $email, 'token' => bcrypt($token)]
    );
```

Now `$token` is the token which is sent via url and `bcrypt($token)` is the encrypted token which is saved in the database.

After getting token you can simply send email to user with url like `http://website.com/password/newresetpage/{{$email}}/{{$token}}`

In your new reset password page which will be same as previous one, just hide the email field and set the field by `$email` from the url.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>


                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$email}}" required hidden="true">


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Reset Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
     </form>
```